# why during decryption and encryption we convert hex values to bytes?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes

```
def check_admin(cookie, iv):
    cookie = bytes.fromhex(cookie)
    iv = bytes.fromhex(iv)

    try:
        cipher = AES.new(KEY, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        decrypted = cipher.decrypt(cookie)
        unpadded = unpad(decrypted, 16)
    except ValueError as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}

    if b"admin=True" in unpadded.split(b";"):
        return {"flag": FLAG}
    else:
        return {"error": "Only admin can read the flag"}
```

WHY are we using converting hex to bytes **(cookie = bytes.fromhex(cookie))** in this function ?

Comment: Note that above code is not so secure, AES in CBC mode doesn't contain any integrity / authenticity of the message, and it could be that if repeated decryption ops are allowed that the scheme is vulnerable to a plaintext or padding oracle attack. Uh, don't use without TLS.

Answer (score 1):

Hexadecimals are generally only used as *representation* of bytes (or 16, 24, 32 bit or larger word sizes). The use two characters in the hexadecimal alphabet [0-9A-F] using upper- or lowercase to represent 8 bits / one byte.

Encodings such as hexadecimals exist because of two reasons:

1. we cannot directly print out or read byte values as humans and
2. sometimes we need to incorporate binary values into text.

The latter is the case for cookies, which are set using a (text based) header line in the HTTP protocol.

Modern cryptographic primitives such as AES almost exclusively operate on bits / bytes, both for input and for output and regardless of the mode of operation such as CBC. It doesn't make sense for them to operate on the representation of these bytes in hexadecimals. So we need to convert these hexadecimals back *to the bytes they represent first*.

A better implementation of above would have used base64 or base64url as it is a more compact encoding of the same bytes (~33% overhead vs 100% overhead). Obviously, if text isn't required, then using using the bytes *without encoding* is always best; I see a lot of implementations that encode to hexadecimals or base64 without any good reason.